# Download analytics Lens, Datasets as Excel\CSV using Lightning component

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein, einstein-analytics-dashboards

I wanted to show Einstein analytics datasets or lenses in the lightning component and the user should have a button to download the datasets as excel or csv. Is there anyway to do it? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed Einstein Analytics Dashboards as described here:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_embed_lightning.htm&type=5

(I'm not sure whether lenses can be embedded, but you can just put that lens on a dashboard and then embed that dashboard)

To allow a user to download a csv or xls you have to give him the appropriate permission set:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_setup_download_enable.htm&type=5